# Azure Stream Analytics input blob storage dynamic path pattern

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics

I have an Azure Stream Analytics resource with a Blob Storage as **input** (so **not** output I can read enough docs about that). The problem is that my path pattern is dynamic. We make directories in this Blob Storage to identify batches like so:

/batch-1234/
/batch-5678/
and so on...

I've tried to put "batch-*" in the input path pattern to dynamically assign directories, but this is not allowed.

Is this possible to do with Stream Analytics somehow?

Thank you advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately,`*` is not supported by ASA so far which is stated in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#configure-blob-storage-as-a-stream-input).

[image]

So only `date,time and partition` are supported in file path,no support with `wildcard`.If it is acceptable,you could classify batch-* directory in one root container and leave the `Path Pattern` empty.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please see my sentence: "I've tried to put "batch-*" in the input path pattern to dynamically assign directories, but this is not allowed." So yeah, I know. I hoped that some ASA guru on here had an innovative idea.

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan Okey,so i'm afraid there is no innovative idea to get around this limitation here. Maybe you could submit feedback to ASA  team to support wildcard in the future.

Comment: Too bad. Already upvoted the question on their feedback page. ;) Data Factory Blob Storage connectors have it... Oh well. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan Yeah,ADF copy activity has wildcard built-in feature.If it is acceptable, maybe you could jump into ADF.I'm familiar with ADF,if you need any assistance,please let me know.

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan Hi,if no updates here currently,would you please mark it to end this case for others' reference? After all, this is restriction of product. If you have further ADF questions, you could post here and i will follow that. Thank you.