# Azure Stream Analytic Output

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-log-analytics

[image: Real time Stream Analytic output]

Azure Stream Analytic storing directory like this. Earlier we used datepath
(2022/04/14) for path pattern and its output store separate directory in datalake. Now it has changed storing directory like
'2022%2F4%2F19'. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the Azure Stream Analytic Output you can mention the **Path pattern, Date format**, and **Time format**. All are **optional** properties we can use to filter out.

#### Path pattern

- You can mention the Path pattern which is used to locate the blob within the specified container.
- **Do not include a path pattern if you wish to read blobs from the container's root.**
- You can specify one or more instances of the following three variables within the path:{date}`,` {time}`, or` {partition}`

**Example :** `cluster1/logs/{date}/{time}/{partition}`

#### Date format

The date format in which the files are structured if you utilize the **date** variable in the path.
**Example:**
`YYYY/MM/DD`

#### Time format

The date format in which the files are structured if you utilize the **Time** variable in the path. Currently, it supports only `HH` (Hours).

##### References:

- [Configure the blob storage as a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#configure-blob-storage-as-a-stream-input)
- [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140982/azure-stream-analytics-input-blob-storage-dynamic-path-pattern) for **Dynamic Path** pattern.
- [Stream analysis Custom path pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-custom-path-patterns-blob-storage-output)

Comment: We used datepath that is a column of our database and it store date like 2022/04/14.
We used this datepath for path pattern (directory/directory/{datepath}) and we don't want to use real time streaming.
Earlier , it's ok in data lake. It store our data with separate directory.At those days,it has changed like that and start storing directory like 2022%2F4%2F19. I can't find solution. I know that it may be easy when we use real time stream analytic. But we don't want to. Is there any solution for that, please?

Comment: This is unexpected, you should open a support ticket in the Azure portal. Are you able to do that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request